# push jsonlog data to elasticsearch

Tags: 7

I have installed the module jsonlog on drupal 7, but there are no information on how can I push the logs to elasticsearch or kibana or logstash. How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [JSONlog project page](https://www.drupal.org/project/jsonlog) states:

> Logs watchdog events JSON-formatted to log files. **Provides a Logstash/ElasticSearch-ready log source**.

The module only does one thing: turn Drupal watchdog events into JSON-loggable files and writes them to whatever server dir you've configured for it.

Before using this module you will need to:

- Setup [ElasticSearch](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch) & [Kibana](https://github.com/elastic/kibana). This is a separate task from setting up LogStash. It will depend on your service provider (this is off-topic for Drupal Answers).
- [Setup LogStash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/setup-logstash.html). This will vary based on whatever app server you're running Drupal on. You'll have to find instructions applicable to the app server running Drupal.